# Application getting crashed while setting image in a variable

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to store an image in a variable, but my application is getting crashed on the below given line:

```
let theImage = UIImage(named: self.arrImages[indexPath.row])!
```

Here, `arrImages` is an array which contains images.

Crash which I am getting is

> Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values

**Edit 1**
As required by @Duncan C & @Valentin
**Declaration:**

```
var arrImages = [String]()
```

Using it in delegate of `UICollectionView`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if collectionView == self.collectionView
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageCell

        cell.imageView.image = nil
        var theImage = UIImage()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {

            if let image = UIImage(named: self.arrImages[indexPath.row]) {
                // Do whatever you like with the image here
                 theImage = UIImage(named: self.arrImages[indexPath.row])!
            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                cell.imageView.image =  theImage
                cell.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

            });
        })

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: are the values the correct image names?

Comment: @luk2302: Yes I have confirmed that too...

Comment: then try to split the actual image creation and the unwrapping and take a look of the image returned by the constructor is nil.

Comment: @luk2302 not able to get your last comment

Comment: basically remove the `!` at the end and see what `theImage` is - pretty much what @Valentin suggested.

Comment: Does `self.arrImages` contain the actual `UIImage`s or the *names* (`Strings`) of `UIImage`s? This should be extremely easy to debug *if you use the debugger and look at the intermediate values*

Comment: Name of images as String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing enough information, and some of the things you did say do not make sense.

Post the declaration of your arrImages, as well as the code that installs values into the array.

You say that your array contains images, but your code is expecting the array to contain image filenames (strings).

Next, you need to break your code into steps and debug it:

```
let index = indexPath.row
let imageName = self.arrImages[index];
println("At index \(index), imageName = \"\(imageName)\"")
let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
println("Image = \(image)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding it with

```
if let image = UIImage(named: ...) {
    // Do whatever you like with the image here  
}
```

Comment: Let me try, Hope this helps

Comment: I used what you suggested but after that I am getting this error: " malloc: *** error for object 0x790b6400: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"

Comment: There is something wrong with your code - can you post your entire class so that we can analyse it? Optional binding (my code) basically just takes the UIImage(named: ...) and if it exists assigns it to the image constant.